# How do I target a specific Application Pool when using Visual Studio 2012's Web Deploy?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012

My application can not deploy because of the following error:

```
Web deployment task failed. (The application pool that you are trying to use has the 'managedRuntimeVersion' property set to 'v2.0'. This application requires 'v4.0'.)
```

Right now, I'm attempting to deploy my .NET application to IIS. VS is attempting to target the "DefaultAppPool" application pool. I want it to instead target the "ASP .NET v4.0" application pool. How do I do that in Visual Studio?

I am trying to not change any settings within IIS if possible.

Comment: What .NET Framework version is your application targeting?

Comment: Also, do you know what version of ASP.NET is installed on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this would be considered a hack, but it got the job done without any issues.

What I did was I first created a folder in IIS and then converted it to an application. After which, I had it target the .NET 4.0 application pool and voila, Visual Studio was able to deploy the application without the error.

I hope this helps people in the future that Google their issue and come upon my question.